# FB Authentication Server Side

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication, facebook-access-token

I am asking user to login from FB JS SDK. I get accessToken and userID and I save it in a database. And then internally every few minutes I call a php function at the server to check if there is an entry in the database and get all the information I can from accessToken.

The server side code is:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxx',
 ));

$facebook->setAccessToken($savedAccessToken);

$user = $facebook->getUser();

$profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

I am able to login as $user is not 0. But I get the error as:

```
OAuthException: The access token could not be decrypted
```

Please help me resolve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> OAuthException: The access token could not be decrypted

I guess that means you’re passing a value has has been truncated or something (or isn’t an access token at all).

Is your database column holding the access token long enough?

What does a `var_dump` of `$savedAccessToken` say?

Comment: Yes it was getting truncated. Thanks